# CoffeeScript - pass an anonymous function with parameters

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I can't fugure out how to pass an anonymous function that takes a parameter. Here is my situation:

```
class MyClass
  constructor: (@a) ->
    console.log("MyClass: created " + @a)

  show: ->
    console.log("MyClass: show " + @a)
```

then, with UnderscoreJS, this works:

```
_.map listOfMyClassObjects, (obj) -> obj.show
```

but I want to wrap the call to map in a separate function for convinience:

```
allMyClass(fun) ->
  _.map listOfMyClassObjects, fun(obj)
```

so that later I can do:

```
allMyClass((obj) -> obj.show())
```

but the browser console says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fun is not defined
  (anonymous function)
  require../browser.CoffeeScript.run
  ...
```

What is the correct synthax? Also, is it possible to simplify like this?

```
 allMyClass(fun) ->
    _.map listOfMyClassObjects, obj[fun]()

 allMyClass(show())
```

**UPDATE:**

As per Thilo's answer, there was the syntax mistake in the function call. But also, there was a mistake in calling the function on the map iteration result. The working version is this:

```
allMyClass = (fun) ->
  _.map listOfMyClassObjects, (obj) -> fun(obj)
```

Still wandering if there is a shorter version of passing the class method to the `allMyClass` function though.

**UPDATE2:**

Simplification is possible like this:

```
allMyClass = (fun) ->
  _.map listOfMyclassObjects, (obj) -> obj[fun]()

allMyClass("show")
```

Passing arguments to the `fun` would require passing more arguments all in all.

Comment: In CoffeeScript the class body itself is a function expression that gets executed and returns the actual class constructor. So `foo = 1` sets a variable within the scope of the Class body function expression itself. While `foo: 1` sets a `foo` property with a value of `1` on the class prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to define a function

```
allMyClass = (fun) ->
   _.map listOfMyClassObjects, fun(obj)
```

or method

```
allMyClass : (fun) ->
   _.map listOfMyClassObjects, fun(obj)
```

Without the `=` or `:` you were just calling `allMyClass`.

Comment: Oh! Just can't get used to CoffeeScript function notation ))) That's it! However, there was one more issue with my code, which I have depicted in the update.

Comment: For any kind of syntax error, paste the offending lines into "Try CoffeeScript" and see what the JS looks like. http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/